# How to perform inference on regression coefficients when some X values are interpolated?

Tags: regression, inference, missing-data, data-imputation, interpolation

This should be a simple question but I'm having a hard time finding an answer.

Assume I have some data $y$ with covariates $X$. This set of data was obtained via a simple random sample. I want to perform OLS to get an estimate of a function for $E(y | X)$.

However, say some values in $X$ are missing for some observations. By that I mean in my matrix $X$, some cells are missing.

A common approach is to *impute* the missing values in X, by simply filling them in with the means of their respective column. If I know something special about the data I can use a more refined approach, but regardless, assume I am filling in the blank cells using some function on the data that I do have that is not missing. From there, I believe the standard approach is to move on with the regression as if there was nothing wrong with the data to begin with.

Under OLS, we have $\hat{\beta} = \left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X^Ty$. $y$ is normally distributed around $E(y|X)$ with some variance $\sigma^2$, and $\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X^T$ is considered to be "fixed," so $\hat{\beta}$ is just a linear transformation of $y$.

However, as my sample is random, so will be the value(s) that I use to replace the missing data, thus $\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X^T$ is also random, and $\hat{\beta}$ is no longer a simple linear transformation of $y$.

How can I appropriately account for this when performing inference on the regression coefficients? In other words, how should the standard errors change? Should I even account for this to begin with?

Comment: Your "interpolation" appears to be a simple method of *imputation.*  The theory of imputation tells you that considering *why* some values might be missing and analyzing how missingness is associated with the other variables are crucial considerations, and it offers sophisticated but practicable methods such as *multiple imputation* for estimating standard errors, *etc.*

Comment: In addition, an ordinary analysis after the fill-in will give horribly wrong standard errors (too small), and the regression coefficients may be biased.  Multiple imputation is your friend, especially predictive mean matching.  For more see [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/missing.html).

Comment: Thanks both, I understand that there are better and worse approaches to imputation. My question is at a much higher level, no matter what imputation method I use, assuming the replacement for a piece of missing data is a function of the non-missing data, what is the general framework for performing inference?

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell for the link. I will review and refine my question as needed.

Comment: The general framework, to give useful results, needs to incorporate the considerations presented by @FrankHarrell.  In particular, you need to consider how your imputation method affects the results of interest and how uncertain the imputation might be.